# Android - Adding a key listener to an activity programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-activity, keyevent, onkeydown

All I want to do is programatically add an onKeyDown listener to an existing activity.  A little bit of context for what I want to do: I want to make a standalone function that handles click events that occur in a mediaplayer.

ie: Let's pretend I have this class.

```
public class Main extends Activity
{    
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.maingui);
    }

@Override
     public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
         switch (keyCode) {
             case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_FAST_FORWARD:
        }
        return false;
      }
}
```

What I would like to do is add a function that adds the onKeyDown Listener through programming.

ie:

```
    public class Main extends Activity
    {    
    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.maingui);

                createListener();
        }

}
public void createListener()
{
    @Override
         public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

             switch (keyCode) {
                 case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_FAST_FORWARD:
          }
            return false;
    }
}
```

This obviously doesn't work, but gives you a good idea of what I'm trying to do.

This is what I've tried which doesn't work.

```
    public class Main extends Activity
    {    
    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.maingui);

            MyKeyClickClass.createListener(this);
    }

}
```

- Then Imagine this function in a MyKeyClickClass class

  ```
  public static void createListener(Activity act)
      {      
          View testing = act.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);

          testing.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){

              @Override
              public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                  String test = "Hi";

                  return false;
              }
          });
      }
  ```

Is this possibly to do? I'm not getting any response to key events doing it this way.

Cheers

Comment: Maybe I missed something obvious here but what do you expect to happen? You initialize a variable and return false

Comment: I'm confused `onKeyDown()` is already a listener, why do you want to make a listener-listener?

Comment: This is just stub code. I want to dynamically create a keyEventListener. I want to handle a click event that occurs in an activity, but there is no onkeyDown listener instantiated in that activity already. This may seam strange, but I assure you that there is good reasoning. Simply put, I want to know if you can just call a function that creates a key event listener for the whole activity.

Comment: @codeMagic That variable initialization is just something I put a breakpoint on while debugging to see if the code ever reaches that point. Other functionality will be added once I can get this piece figured out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If for whatever reason you can't just use onKeyDown, couldn't you just have onKeyDown pass its parameters to another function?

If you create a myKeyListener class then you can do something like this.

```
 @Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     myKeyListener.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }
```

Comment: That is an interesting idea. But I was hoping to create the listener from scratch. So if the activity has no onKeyDown in it, my function will be called to dynamically create it.  In your case, there would need to be prior knowledge of the custom KeyListener.  This is why in my example above I'm trying to pass in the activity into the function and dynamically create the onKeyListener that way. However it's not working as is.

Comment: Because all activities have default implementations of onKeyDown, you would have to override it to control it. To do it your way, you would have to create a custom KeyDownListener class which would have an onKeyDown method that the main activity's onKeyDown would call. The main activity would need a function like setKeyDownListener which you would use to pass in KeyDownListener objects.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help TSL. I was able to take your advice and implement something that wasn't exactly what I was originally thinking but should work well for my purpose. Thank you!!!